# 404 on static file

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I try to open a static file (a PNG image) in my web browser but it returns a 404.
I then stop and start the website and try again and I can see the image. But as soon as I hit CTRL+F5 in my browser, I will get a 404 again.

Here's a part of the IIS log:

```
2013-04-13 12:37:05 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 200 0 0 1809
2013-04-13 12:37:06 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 304 0 0 78
2013-04-13 12:37:06 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 304 0 0 62
2013-04-13 12:37:06 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 304 0 0 46
2013-04-13 12:37:07 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 304 0 0 62
2013-04-13 12:37:07 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 304 0 0 62
2013-04-13 12:37:15 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 200 0 0 15
2013-04-13 12:37:15 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 200 0 0 15
2013-04-13 12:37:15 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 200 0 0 15
2013-04-13 12:37:15 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 200 0 0 15
2013-04-13 12:37:38 1.2.3.4 GET /files/01/018a9b17-a1ee-47ca-bf6d-9c13667c1dc3.png - 80 user 5.6.7.8 Mozilla/5.0 404 0 0 62
```

As you can see, I was able to get the image a couple of times. But then it returned a 404. I've tried this a few times and the behaviour is the same.

My guess is that it has something to do with caching in IIS. But where should I look?

**update**

I did some analysis with Process Monitor, but to mo me it seems there's nothing wrong there...

[image: process monitor screenshot 404 static files]
[bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQDie.png)

Comment: I see 304s there as well. Is the image physically present? Also, as long as you don't hit CTRL+F5, but F5, your browser will try to load the image from its own cache instead of invoking the server. A bit more details on the scenario would also be helpful.

Comment: the image is there, I see it in the folder on the web server. 304 means that the image is not modified.

I'm hitting ctrl+f5 because it's the server I'm testing. I have to be sure that the image will always load, not just one time

Comment: What are the subcodes of the errors you get? They'd be probably quite helpful in identifying the cause of your problem. IIS logs several 404s, like 404.3 which indicates unknown MIME type - [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/deeac9ef-cf55-4acd-86ce-b46022ff5479.mspx?mfr=true) might be helpful with this case. Also, do the respnose headers (try using Fiddler for example) contain any useful info?

Comment: Thank you. The subcode is 0. It's the number next to 404

Comment: That's bad news. It means that IIS physically does not find the file. I think it's time to analyze the request and response headers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is a Kentico website and by default all requests go through the Kentico router handler. By adding the folder to the exclusion list in Site Manager, Settings, URLs and SEO, Excluded URLs the website now works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the answer for your question:
[IIS Status Codes Documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;318380&x=17&y=8)

For me, the logs are in *C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR\httperr1.log*.

In theory, if you do not see a subcode that means a 404.0